# malformed JSON while JSON is valid?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get a JSON object from an external file, but I always get the error: malformed , that points to the first `{` of my JSON file. I tested my JSON file on this website: http://jsonlint.com/ and it is valid.

This is my JSON code:

```
{
  "employees": [{
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
      "firstName": "Anna",
      "lastName": "Smith"
    }, {
      "firstName": "Peter",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my script:

```
$.getJSON("employe.json", function (data) {
  document.write(data.employees[0].firstName);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you see the error message "malformed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("employe.json", function(data) {
    document.write(data.employees[0].firstName);
    });
 });
</script>
```

Or instead of document write

```
 alert( data.employees[0].firstName);
```

Odds are you are going to want $.each iteration

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("employe.json", function(data) {
      $.each(data.employees, function(arrayID, employee) {
            alert(employee.firstName);
      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason, I could not accept your answer or leave a comment for 9 min.